# What’s the correct term to describe this?

Tags: word-choice

What’s the correct adjective to describe something that has the ability to make someone feel bad about themselves or lose their confidence?

Answer (score 5):

**Disheartening**

> If something is disheartening, it makes you feel disappointed and less confident or less hopeful. -- [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disheartening)

**Demoralizing**

> If something is demoralizing, it makes you lose so much confidence in what you are doing that you want to give up. -- [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/demoralizing)

---

If something just has the *ability* to make you feel bad or lose confidence, you may want to qualify these words by saying "potentially disheartening" or "potentially demoralizing".